# Django logging only logs "root", no other handlers

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

This is my Django logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {"require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"}},
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s "
            "%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
            'include_html': True,
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose",
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": os.path.join(APPS_DIR + "..", "app.log"),
        },
        'db_queries': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(APPS_DIR + "..", 'db_queries.log'),
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "level": "WARNING", 
        "handlers": ["file", "mail_admins"],
        "propagate": True,
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["file", "mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "django.security.DisallowedHost": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "handlers": ["file", "mail_admins"],
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "django": {
             "handlers": ["file"], 
             "level": "DEBUG", 
             "propagate": True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['db_queries'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

The "root" logger works, both for file and mails_admin, but the other loggers don't seem to do anything. I would expect that at least the "django" and "django.db.backends" handlers would write something to file.

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Edit: `django.db.backends` only works when `DEBUG=True` apparently, so that explains that part. I still don't understand why the "django" logger doesn't work.

Comment: How did you test this? This configuration works as expected, in a clean django 4.1 project. For example: starting the local test server causes queries to be logged to file, and it causes (duplicated) debug output to be logged to file.

Comment: Note that you'll get duplicate log entries, because you've added the same handlers both to the root logger and to some child loggers with `propagate=True`. For example, the `django` logger will log to file, then pass the message to its parent's handlers (`root`), which log the same message to file again (disregarding the root logger level). See [docs for logging.Logger.propagate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate).

Comment: It has been a while and I solved it since then. I'm not sure what the issue was then. Thanks for your feedback though!